# Count minutes between first and last tuple and group by username

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that stores data regarding users that visit a system. As the user is browsing the system, I am storing their location, username, date and time in an Oracle 11g database. My table looks like this:

```
    username   date           time          location

    user1      YYYY-MM-DD    HH24:MI:SS     kitchen
    user2      YYYY-MM-DD    HH24:MI:SS     bathroom
```

I need a query that will calculate the minutes between the first and last log of each day, for each particular username. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: What are the datatypes of date and time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `date` and `time` are varchar2,
Try:

```
with t as
(
   select username, "date", to_date("date"||time, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS') dt
   from your_table 
)
select username, "date",  (max(dt)- min(dt)) * 1440
from t
group by username, "date"
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/346fd/4)

Comment: They're not. They're both date with the format described above. Date: YYYY-MM-DD and time: HH24:MI:SS

Comment: @junkystu, a `date` in oracle is a number representing a date + time it doesn't have a format...

Answer (score 0):

Group by username, max + min by date? (you probably will need to combine it with [dense rank](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php)

Something like (pseudo code)

```
SELECT  . . .
FROM
(SELECT
select *, 
-- dates
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(date) ORDER BY date DESC) AS rank 
                 FROM
                    your_table
)
) t1
WHERE RANK = 1      
group by
```

Comment: I need to calculate the minutes between the first and last log of each day, for each particular username. So that won't work. Thanks